# After new elements has been injected run JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I been looking for the way to do this since yesterday, I have a `<div class="list">` where I append some element using `PHP`

**HTML:**

```
<div id="list"></div>
<input type="button" value="Populate" onClick="populate();">
```

**Javascript**

```
function populate(){
    var url = 'http://mylink.com/edit.php?region_name='+region_name;
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: url,  
                success:function(results){  
                    $('#list').html(results);
                }

            });
}
```

Then my generated `HTML` after running clicking on the button is;

```
<div id="list">
 <label>region</label>
 <br>
 <div class="edit">
    <input class="num" type="text" value="east" readonly="">
 </div>
</div>
```

As it is not in a right structure, I want to run a `JQuery` after the elements has been populated

```
var length = $('.edit').length;
for(var a = 0; a <= length - 1; a++){
$('.edit:eq('+ a +')').find('input').appendTo($('label:eq('+ a +')'));
```

Fiddle sample [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2bvJY/1/).

And BTW, I tried to bind it with  `DOMSubTreeModified`

```
$("#List").bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
    //My JQuery
});
```

But still no result.

Comment: Call your jquery function inside ajax's success block..

Comment: I already tried that, but tried again but still no result. Well the result is that `HTML` has been populated but without the `JQuery` being called.

Comment: Did u tried ajax's done block ?

Comment: That nop. Let me check that one.

Comment: Thanks that was a great help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

call your js function in done block

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
}).done(function() {
//your jquery method
});
```